# How can I use a custom footerTemplate for Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid that has x number of columns for the header and the content. I want to have a footer for it that has only two columns. The first column should have a colspan of y and the other, (x - y).

How can I achieve this footerTemplate? From what I understand, Kendo just copies the  to the header, content, and footer tables. Doesn't having more  tags than  tags make the HTML invalid?

Here is a sample of what I want to achieve:

[image]

Thank you.